# Is there any possibility to make hard or soft link between two or more linux systems?

Tags: linux, unix

My query is that i want to make hard/soft link  in two different linux system.

eg

```
A:192.168.14.112 B:192.168.14.110

ls -n /var/www/html/xyz.txt root@192.168.14.110:/var/www/html/abc.txt
```

or is there any other method to make link.

Basically i want make a link/connection that point to file that is in different system.

Suppose to anybody write into file_1 that is located in machine_A and same time reflect into machine_B(It is not a replication).

file_1(192.168.14.112)->file_2(192.168.14.110)

Any body is using file_2 in machine_B it is working same as file_1 in machine_A .

thanks in advance

Comment: You probably want to `mount`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mount the filesystem from server A on server B or vice versa, through NFS. Or you should look intro cluster filesystems like GFS or OCFS.

Answer (score 1):

Network File System (NFS) maybe?